# WindowManager$BadTokenException when using Qualtrics on Huawei

Tags: java, android, qualtrics

I am using the [Qualtrics](https://reporting.qualtrics.com/SolutionPortal/solutions/app-si-docs/#/quickstart) library in order to trigger surveys. When a survey is triggered a dialog pops up which works fine. The dialog has a spinner for choosing a language. But, on `Huawei P8`, when I click the spinner for choosing a different language, the app is crashing with the following stacktrace:

> 07-14 16:11:14.466 13387-13387/ W/System.err: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
>   07-14 16:11:14.466 13387-13387/ W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:606)
>   07-14 16:11:14.466 13387-13387/ W/System.err:     at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:282)
>   07-14 16:11:14.466 13387-13387/ W/System.err:     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
>   07-14 16:11:14.466 13387-13387/ W/System.err:     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:325)
>   07-14 16:11:14.466 13387-13387/ W/System.err:     at com.android.org.chromium.content.browser.input.SelectPopupDialog.show(SelectPopupDialog.java:126)
>   07-14 16:11:14.466 13387-13387/ W/System.err:     at com.android.org.chromium.content.browser.ContentViewCore.showSelectPopup(ContentViewCore.java:2818)
>   07-14 16:11:14.466 13387-13387/ W/System.err:     at com.android.org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.nativeDoRunLoopOnce(Native Method)
>   07-14 16:11:14.466 13387-13387/ W/System.err:     at com.android.org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.handleMessage(SystemMessageHandler.java:28)
>   07-14 16:11:14.466 13387-13387/ W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>   07-14 16:11:14.466 13387-13387/ W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>   07-14 16:11:14.466 13387-13387/ W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5538)
>   07-14 16:11:14.466 13387-13387/ W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>   07-14 16:11:14.466 13387-13387/ W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>   07-14 16:11:14.466 13387-13387/ W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:958)
>   07-14 16:11:14.466 13387-13387/ W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:753)

This is how I invoke the dialog

```
public void startSurvey() {
        //Unload previous intercepts
        qualtricsIntercept.unload();

        //Trigger Qualtrics.
        qualtricsIntercept.put(Constants.QUALTRICS_INTERCEPT_KEY, Constants.QUALTRICS_INTERCEPT_VALUE, false);
        //Start the Qualtrics Dialog
        qualtricsIntercept.loadWithViewGroup((ViewGroup) mainActivity.findViewById(android.R.id.content));
    }
```